# Show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} tF(t) = 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow R$ be a continuous function and define
$$F(t) = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{t}} f(tx)\cos(t^2x) dx.$$

Show that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} tF(t) = 0.$

This is part of a question from an old analysis qualifying at my university. I came across it while trying to study for my final exam (I'm an undergrad). I have honestly not seen a problem like this before, so I am not sure how to proceed. Can I please have a hint?

I tried integration by parts, but that was a disaster.
Another technique I know to make integrals nice is the second mean value theorem for integrals, but that doesn't apply since neither $f(tx)$ nor $\cos(t^2x)$ are not necessarily non-negative for all $x$. Not sure what to try next, or if this question is even in the scope of what was covered in my class.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma? After the change of variables, RL finishes off the problem immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the change of variable $y=tx$ to see that 
$$
tF(t) = \int_0^1 f(y) \cos(ty) dy.
$$

Let $\epsilon >0$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, which is compact, we can use the Weierstrass approximation theorem to pick a polynomial $p$ such that 
$$
\sup_{y \in [0,1]} |p(y) - f(y)| < \epsilon.
$$
Then 
$$
\left\vert tF(t) - \int_0^1 p(y) \cos(ty) dy \right \vert \le \int_0^1 \vert [f(y)-p(y) ]\cos(ty) \vert dy \le \int_0^1 \epsilon = \epsilon. 
$$

Now we integrate by parts:
$$
\int_0^1 p(y) \cos(ty) dy = \int_0^1 p(y) \frac{d}{dy} \frac{\sin(ty)}{t} dy 
= p(1) \frac{\sin(t)}{t} - \frac{1}{t} \int_0^1 p'(y) \sin(ty) dy.
$$
Choose $T$ large enough so that $|p(1)|/T < \epsilon$ and so that 
$$
\frac{1}{T} \int_0^1 \vert p'(y) \vert dy < \epsilon.
$$
Then for $t > T$ we have that 
$$
\left\vert \int_0^1 p(y) \cos(ty) dy \right\vert < 2 \epsilon.
$$

Hence $t > T$ implies that 
$$
\vert tF(t) \vert < 3 \epsilon,
$$
and so $tF(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite follow how you changed the bounds on your integral, but the rest makes sense.

Comment: If $y=tx$ then $dy = t dx$ and so $dx = dy / t$, which explains where the $t$ goes when we multiply $t F(t)$.  For the bounds, we have that if $x=0$ then $y = tx = t0 =0$ and if $x=1/t$ then $y = tx = t/t =1$, so in the "y coordinates" the bounds of integration are from $y=0$ to $y=1$.  Make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: Why not just use the Riemann Lebesgue lemma?

Comment: @zhw. This is effectively a proof of Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: Yes I know. I just wonder why you don't mention RL, as that was surely the route the qualifying exam authors had in mind.

Comment: @zhw I do not know the RL lemma, perhaps it is covered in the second semester of the course.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestion that might be useful.
We can rewrite the integral as following:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t\to \infty}tF(t) = \lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)cos(tx)dx
\end{equation}
You see, as $t \to \infty$, $cos(tx)$ oscillates very fast between -1 and +1. Because $f(x)$ is a continuous function, so the integral will be 0.